# Bunifu rounded corners for Windows Form - C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using Bunifu framework to design UI for C# project. I want to make rounded corners for my Windows form but `Bunifu_Classes` does not exsist - how to fix this?

Is there a way to add `Bunifu_Classes`?

I have seen this code for rounded corners to Windows form:

```
Bunifu_Classes.Round.ActivateForm(this, 20);
```

[image]

Comment: You can see the link may be help you https://wedevelopersblog.wordpress.com/2017/07/12/bunifu-net-ui-framework-1-5-3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Toolkit you will find **BunifuElipse** Component - drag and drop on your form, select **TargetControl** [your form ] change the **ElipseRadius** Property to whichever size you want, recommended size is 5. Also accompany with **BunifuDrag** Component to make the borderless form draggable. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

to round the corners of your form you must use Bunifu.Framework.Lib.Elipse like this:
--Bunifu.Framework.Lib.Elipse.Apply(this, 20)
after --InitializeComponent() in form constructor.

good Look.